# How to grant "su" rights using knox?

Tags: android, superuser, samsung-knox

Is it possible at all to grant "su" rights using Knox permissions?
I thought if I activate knox licence key and provide    com.samsung.android.knox.permission.KNOX_ENTERPRISE_DEVICE_ADMIN permission that will give me "su" rights? Anyone had any experience with that kind of stuff?